# Unable to build MIT Kerberos in Windows 2007 (Windows Server Enterprise)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windbg, kerberos

I was trying to build MIT Kerberos In Windows 2007 (Windows Server Enterprise) Service Pack 2 32 bit system. After adding a few flags specific to posix errors I was able to build it in Windows 7 (along with working kinit and klist programs). However in win 2007 all exes generated crash whenever I attempt to execute them. I had used Microsoft visual studio 2008 with Microsoft SDK v6 for both builds.

```
Crash code in event viewer: Exception code: 0xc000041d and occasionally 0xc00008c
                            Fault offset: 0x76e011f1
```

After enabling all possible checks in gflags and running kinit, I noticed a message saying unable to start application due to incorrect security permissions. I changed compatibility mode to xp3 and ran as administrator but no luck.

I then used sxstrace to determine any link time inconsistencies. I didnt find even a single line in my parsed trace file. I then used dependency walker and it wasnt able to find any errors.

I then used procdump and windbg to get the dump of the problem. Unfortunately I havent been able to locate a suitable pdb for nt.dll. This is what i found after attempting to unwind the core dump stack (kp command):-

```
0018975c 64754d57 user32!GetProcessWindowStation+0x15
0018a8c0 64755d08 msvcr90d!CrtDbgReport+0x437
0018f954 64754992 msvcr90d!VCrtDbgReportA+0x7d8
0018f974 6475494b msvcr90d!CrtDbgReport+0x72
0018f99c 646bc34d msvcr90d!CrtDbgReport+0x2b
0018f9d0 646bc812 msvcr90d!get_pgmptr+0x1bd
0018fa08 646bc711 msvcr90d!_getmainargs+0x182
0018fa1c 76fc99a0 msvcr90d!_getmainargs+0x81
0018fa3c 76fcd939 ntdll!RtlQueryEnvironmentVariable+0x241
0018fb30 76fd686c ntdll!LdrResSearchResource+0xb4d
0018fcb0 76fd5326 ntdll!RtlGetNtVersionNumbers+0x9b
0018fd00 76fc9ef9 ntdll!RtlSetUnhandledExceptionFilter+0x50
0018fd10 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10
```

I dont quite understand what this means and I have no idea what on earth is going on. I dont have too much proficiency in using windbg

Is there anything else that anyone can suggest me to narrow down the root cause of the issue? Even after I copy the 2k7 built binaries to my local win 7 machine and it still crashes with the same stack.

Edit: after running .symfix, .reload and then analyze -v I got the following output in windbg console:-

```
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for klist.exe
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for klist.exe

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  000014bc

PROCESS_NAME:  klist.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  klist.exe

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_BREAKPOINT_AFTER_CALL

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT_AFTER_CALL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT_AFTER_CALL

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 6475450f to 74c49eff

STACK_TEXT:  
00189718 6475450f 0018973c 0018a8c0 64754cc0 user32!NtUserGetProcessWindowStation+0x15
0018975c 64754d57 001898b0 64696070 00012012 msvcr90d!__crtMessageBoxA+0x14f
0018a8c0 64755d08 00000001 00000000 00000000 msvcr90d!__crtMessageWindowA+0x3b7
0018f954 64754992 00000001 00000000 00000000 msvcr90d!_VCrtDbgReportA+0x7d8
0018f974 6475494b 00000001 00000000 00000000 msvcr90d!_CrtDbgReportV+0x22
0018f99c 646bc34d 00000001 00000000 00000000 msvcr90d!_CrtDbgReport+0x2b
0018f9d0 646bc812 00000022 6e76fe50 0018faec msvcr90d!_NMSG_WRITE+0x6d
0018fa08 646bc711 64680000 00000001 0018fd24 msvcr90d!__CRTDLL_INIT+0xf2
0018fa1c 76fc99a0 64680000 00000001 0018fd24 msvcr90d!_CRTDLL_INIT+0x21
0018fa3c 76fcd939 646bc6f0 64680000 00000001 ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x14
0018fb30 76fd686c 0018fd24 7efdd000 7efde000 ntdll!LdrpRunInitializeRoutines+0x26f
0018fcb0 76fd5326 0018fd24 76f90000 734dc02c ntdll!LdrpInitializeProcess+0x1400
0018fd00 76fc9ef9 0018fd24 76f90000 00000000 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x78
0018fd10 00000000 0018fd24 76f90000 00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x10


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
msvcr90d!__crtMessageBoxA+14f [f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtmbox.c @ 121]
6475450f 8945ec          mov     dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE:  f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtmbox.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_FILE:  f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtmbox.c

FAULTING_SOURCE_LINE_NUMBER:  121

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1

SYMBOL_NAME:  msvcr90d!__crtMessageBoxA+14f

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: msvcr90d

IMAGE_NAME:  msvcr90d.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  488ef6c7

STACK_COMMAND:  dt ntdll!LdrpLastDllInitializer BaseDllName ; dt ntdll!LdrpFailureData ; ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT_AFTER_CALL_80000003_msvcr90d.dll!__crtMessageBoxA

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_BREAKPOINT_AFTER_CALL_msvcr90d!__crtMessageBoxA+14f

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/klist_exe/4_0_0_0/533e75fb/unknown/0_0_0_0/bbbbbbb4/80000003/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Edit: After running in Visual Studio I got the following output:-

```
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\WS\TPL\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEBUG\bin\klist.exe', Symbols loaded.
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sysfer.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\WS\TPL\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEBUG\bin\k5sprt32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\WS\TPL\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEBUG\bin\msvcr90d.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\WS\TPL\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEBUG\bin\krb5_32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\WS\TPL\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEBUG\bin\comerr32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\WS\TPL\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEBUG\bin\wshelp32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dnsapi.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'
'klist.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x74c49eff in klist.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000250.


 *** An Access Violation occurred in "C:\WS\TPL\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEBUG\bin\klist.exe" :

The instruction at 0000000076E011F1 tried to read from an invalid address, 0000000000000250

 *** enter .exr 000000000008E970 for the exception record
 ***  enter .cxr 000000000008E480 for the context
 *** then kb to get the faulting stack

Unhandled exception at 0x74c49eff in klist.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.

> kb
 Index  Function
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*1      user32.dll!74c49eff() 
 2      [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for user32.dll]
 3      user32.dll!74c49eff() 
 4      msvcr90d.dll!58f8450f() 
 5      msvcr90d.dll!58f84d57()
```

I cant get klist or krb5 dlls in the stack at all. Since klist or any other mit kerb dll does not appear in this section, I am unable to load check their symbols. This is very frustrating, I will attempt to build my own sample program and check for issues. Btw did I miss any analysis steps?

Edit : After checking for first argument to crtmessagebox I got :-

```
001898b0  "Debug Error!..Program: C:\WS\TPL"
001898d0  "\src\MitKerberos\1.11.1\BUILDDEB"
001898f0  "UG\bin\klist.exe..R6034..An appl"
00189910  "ication has made an attempt to l"
00189930  "oad the C runtime library withou"
00189950  "t using a manifest..This is an u"
00189970  "nsupported way to load Visual C+"
00189990  "+ DLLs. You need to modify your "
001899b0  "application to build with a mani"
001899d0  "fest..For more information, see "
001899f0  "the "Visual C++ Libraries as Sha"
00189a10  "red Side-by-Side Assemblies" top"
```

As far as I understand the program responsible for this is mt.exe and I had run it.

Comment: You can fix your symbols using the command `.symfix;.reload` then execute `!analyze -v` and post the output

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, I executed your steps exactly as you mentioned and I am adding the stack trace as an edit to the question

Comment: What is `klist.exe` is this from kerberos? Looks to me like the dll is failing to load, could you try launching your app from visual studio or windbg and executing until it crashes, better yet run the debug build or disable optimizations for release build so you get sensible stack traces and don't strip private symbols

Comment: klist is one of the exes generated during MIT Kerberos build(its used to view tickets issued by kerberos). The build I am using is a debug build but all stack symbols inside windbg point to system libaries like ntdll (which is worriesome). I will run my app in visual studio and see what happens. I dont know what all options are enabled during debug build and I will investigate and let you know about the set of symbols.

Comment: the `ntdll` symbols are probably correct as nt implements the kerberos authentication system, if you build debug then optimization is already off. If you can then execute from within Visual studio, it should catch the exception and the call stack should help you pinpoint the problem

Comment: I ran it in visual studio and added the output (.exr and .cxr were shown as bad commands in visual studio command windows) I will see if I can run them in windbg

Comment: one question - mit kerberos does not come with a solution file nor a cmakeLists file to create one. It would be easier to debug with a solution file. Is there some other way to automatically create a soltuion/vcproj for MIT kerb? I dont see this issue in linux so gdb is out of question. Is there any command line debugger counterpart to gdb in windows that I could probably use?

Comment: You could install cygwin on Windows and use gdb that way but I have no knowledge about that at all, I don't know if that would necessarily help but you could give it a try. The reason I say that is because you are running an exe on Windows and Visual studio and WinDbg are designed for debugging applications on Windows, using a 3rd party tool may introduce incorrect information but you could give it a go, there are other debuggers (some not free) like ollydbg and ida pro

Comment: The first arg to __crtMessageBoxA may provide a hint. Try `da 001898b0` and see if it's a string.

Comment: Hi, I added output of da 001898b0 in the question itself.

Comment: Well I was able to partially resolve my issue. It seems that manifest was not getting embedded with the exes because the configuration script is badly designed (it requrires a Visual studio 8 directory to be defined in program files. While the exes no longer crash, R6034 errors now come while executing my sample program with the dlls.